# SQL Update Table Where date = MIN(date)

Tags: mysql, sql, min

I got the following code:

```
Update `Table` set amount='1003' WHERE date = (SELECT MIN(date)) AND `id` = 736
```

Something is wrong with my first Where rule `date = (SELECT MIN(date))` but i  dont know what.

Comment: Is this MySQL? Please tag with your DBMS. Also, your select statement should be from a table i.e. `select min(date) from sometable`

Comment: you need a `... FROM MyTable` in your subquery.

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the usage of the dreaded backticks

Comment: Your amount is a VarChar or why do you `set amount='1003'`?

Comment: the type is int .... but this shouldnt be the Problem. ist working If i just use the query with Where `id` = 736

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update it from a join:

```
Update `Table` a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `id`, min(exp_date) AS exp_date from `Table` WHERE `id`= 736
) AS b ON (a.id=b.id AND a.exp_date=b.exp_date)
set amount='1003'
WHERE a.id = 736 AND a.exp_date=b.exp_date;
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you!