# SQL UPDATE with WHERE and MIN criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've really tried with this problem and it's taking too much of my time now.  I just need it to work to demo other features of the program to my students.  I and they will not need anything this complex

I have a query where I need to update a table (bids) based on finding a field (design_code) and the minimum of the bid_amount

I have gotten as far as this

```
UPDATE Bids a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DesignCode, MIN(Bid_Amount) AS Bid_Amount 
            FROM Bids 
            WHERE DesignCode = "FT1") AS b 
    ON (a.DesignCode=b.DesignCode AND a.Bid_Amount =b.Bid_Amount) 
SET Bid_Currently_Successful = No 
WHERE a.DesignCode = "FT1" AND a.Bid_Amount =b.Bid_Amount; ');
```

This is based on [SQL Update Table Where date = MIN(date)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40171682/sql-update-table-where-date-mindate)

But I get the error:

> Circular reference caused by Bid_Amount in select

I think I know why, duplicate names, but don't know which to change

I also get the error:

> Your query does not include the specified expression 'DesignCode' as aprt of an aggregate function.

If I do change the AS Bid_Amount's name

Comment: This question could be improved by providing sample data and expected output as text in the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, hello Mr. Lee and welcome to stackoverflow.
Secondly, in the inner query 
`SELECT DesignCode, MIN(Bid_Amount) AS Bid_Amount FROM Bids WHERE DesignCode = "FT1"`
you are trying to use an aggregate function with another column. Usually, to solve this issue, you have to use the `group by` clause with the column that is not in the aggregate function.
 BUT, this changes what you need, as this will be returning the rows as *the minimum amount for each DesignCode*. That's not what you want.
What you want is the primary key for the row, which has the lowest of all bid amounts, so that, you can update the table `bids` with it.
So your inner query would be something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 DesignCode, Bid_Amount FROM Bids ORDER BY Bid_Amount
```

This will return the top row, when ordered in ascending order of `Bid_Amount`.
So, your overall query would be something like:

```
UPDATE Bids a
SET Bid_Currently_Successful = 'No'
WHERE
    a.Bidders = (
                    SELECT TOP 1 Bidders 
                    FROM Bids 
                    WHERE DesignCode = 'FT1' 
                    ORDER BY Bid_Amount
                )
    AND a.date_time_of_bid = (
                                 SELECT TOP 1 date_time_of_bid 
                                 FROM Bids 
                                 WHERE DesignCode = 'FT1'
                                 ORDER BY Bid_Amount
                             )
```

I think, this should work fine.
But I dont think that is a clean way, so, here is another way I would approach this...

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Bid_Currently_Successful = 'No'
FROM 
    Bids a
    INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT TOP 1
                      Bidders, date_time_of_bid
                  FROM
                      Bids
                  WHERE
                      DesignCode LIKE 'FT1'
                  ORDER BY
                      Bid_Amount
    ) b ON b.Bidders = a.Bidders AND b.date_time_of_bid = a.date_time_of_bid
```

I think this is a much cleaner and faster way. In this approach I made it sure that the only row, that gets joined with the `Bids` table is the one that fits your condition.
Though, I should advise, I haven't checked this approach, but it seemed a fun and faster way to do it.

Happy teaching.. :)

---

EDIT1: In case, you are using MySQL, the query would be:

```
UPDATE Bids a
SET Bid_Currently_Successful = 'No'
WHERE
    a.Bidders = (
                    SELECT Bidders 
                    FROM Bids 
                    WHERE DesignCode = 'FT1' 
                    ORDER BY Bid_Amount
                    LIMIT 1
                )
    AND a.date_time_of_bid = (
                                 SELECT date_time_of_bid 
                                 FROM Bids 
                                 WHERE DesignCode = 'FT1'
                                 ORDER BY Bid_Amount
                                 LIMIT 1
                             )
```

and the cleaner approach would be:

```
UPDATE a
SET a.Bid_Currently_Successful = 'No'
FROM 
    Bids a
    INNER JOIN (
                  SELECT
                      Bidders, date_time_of_bid
                  FROM
                      Bids
                  WHERE
                      DesignCode LIKE 'FT1'
                  ORDER BY
                      Bid_Amount
                  LIMIT 1
    ) b ON b.Bidders = a.Bidders AND b.date_time_of_bid = a.date_time_of_bid
```

Thanks P.Salmon for the edit.

---

EDIT2: Thanks for the table details Mr. Lee. Helped me a lot. And also added the where condition, that I seemed to miss.

Comment: The mysql equivalent of top is limit.

Comment: Hi guys.  Thanks for the help.  However that code does what I had a few days ago where ALL successful bids with FT1 change to unsuccessful :'-(  I'm connecting to access by the way (not my call, school's choice before I got here)

Comment: That would be the case, as the differentiating factor between all the rows might not be the column, 'DesignCode'. If you could specify the structure of tables and some sample data, it would be a lot more helpful... :)

Comment: "What you want is the primary key for the row, which has the lowest of all bid amounts, so that, you can update the table bids with it."  If the primary key is important then that is a composite of two other fields, bidders and date_time_of_bid

Comment: Table bidders > Bidders(PK), address details etc.  Table Bids > DateTime, Bidders (composite key), BidAmount, DesignCode, CurrentlySuccessful.  Table Designs > DesignCode(PK), Description, ReservePrice, MinSuccessfulBid.  Table Plots > PlotID, DesignCode

Comment: DateTime      BidAmount    DesignCode    CurrentlySuccessful
=Now            130,000         DT1                 Tickbox

Comment: Hi guys. Once again thanks for the help.  I'm not using mySQL i'm connecting to Access so I just get syntax errors using these.  Sorry for the slow reply I'm busy right now.  I didn't put the mysql tag in by the way

Answer (score 0):

This should work in MySQL:

```
UPDATE Bids b JOIN
       (SELECT b.DesignCode, MIN(Bid_Amount) AS Min_Bid_Amount 
        FROM Bids b
        WHERE b.DesignCode = 'FT1'
        GROUP BY b.DesignCode
       ) d
       ON b.DesignCode = d.DesignCode AND 
          b.Bid_Amount = d.Min_Bid_Amount) 
SET b.Bid_Currently_Successful = 'No' 
WHERE b.DesignCode = 'FT1' ;
```

Most of the changes are cosmetic, but still useful:

- Alias on `Bid_Currently_Successful`.  This is a good practice when using joins in the update.
- Single quotes instead of double quotes around string constants.
- Single quotes around `no` (unless that is a column in your data).
- `GROUP BY` in the subquery.

Comment: Hi guys. Once again thanks for the help.  I'm not using mySQL i'm connecting to Access so I just get syntax errors using these.  Sorry for the slow reply I'm busy right now.  I didn't put the mysql tag in by the way

Comment: @MrLee . . . You should ask *another* question.  This one has been answered multiple times, assuming the database is MS Access.  If you just re-tag this question, you won't get an answer *and* others will see the incompatible answers and might downvote the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I did it!  Thanks for the help guys, it helped me to figure it out.  Probably isn't pretty but I've other things to do so I don't care

UPDATE Bids a SET Bid_Currently_Successful = No 
WHERE (((a.Bidders)=(SELECT TOP 1 Bidders FROM Bids  WHERE Bid_Currently_Successful = Yes AND DesignCode = 'FT1' ORDER BY Bid_Amount)) 
AND ((a.date_time_of_bid)=(SELECT TOP 1 date_time_of_bid FROM Bids 
WHERE Bid_Currently_Successful = Yes AND DesignCode = 'FT1'  ORDER BY Bid_Amount)));

All the extra brackets courtesy of Access...